# Visual Studio C# Getting a list of groups a user is in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to have the code so that it takes a username and outputs a list of groups that the user is a part of on my domain. I am currently just running this on a console application but I will need it to run on a ASP .NET Web Application once the code is complete.

I currently have this as my starting code.

```
public List<GroupPrincipal> GetGroups(string userName)
    {
        List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

        // establish domain context
        PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // find your user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, userName);

        // if found - grab its groups
        if (user != null)
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

            // iterate over all groups
            foreach (Principal p in groups)
            {
                // make sure to add only group principals
                if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                {
                    result.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: So where are you running into problems?

Comment: It simply just doesn't return anything. I guess I am just a little confused as to where to go from here.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? It's hard to know where you may be going wrong without knowing if something is null or zero on the way down to where you're adding items to your results list.

Comment: I've tried to isolate sections and see if I could figure out if it was running but I am pretty new to this so I am not even really sure what I am looking for or how to tell if something is empty just by looking at it.

Comment: Okay. If you are using Visual Studio, you need to set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method. Run the program, then you can hover over the variable names and see what's "in" them at any point in the program. Step to the next line by pressing F12. In this case you need to make sure `user` and `groups` are not empty and that the `result.Add` statement is actually being executed.